# Cannot connect with Huawei E3131 3GMax USB Modem

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager, modem, ppp, netctl

I tried both `netctl` and `NetworkManager`.

Copied `/etc/netctl/examples/mobile_ppp` and added **number** and **APN** name as there's no pin/pass/username and set interface to `/dev/ttyUSB0` (also tried the other `ttyUSB1`, and `ttyUSB2` as well).

```
My `/etc/netctl/mobile_ppp` file's contents are as follows:

Description='Example PPP mobile connection'
Interface='ttyUSB0'
Connection='mobile_ppp'
PhoneNumber='*99#'
# Use default route provided by the peer (default: true)
#DefaultRoute=true
# Use DNS provided by the peer (default: true)
#UsePeerDNS=true
# The user and password are not always required
#User='example@yourprovider.com'
#Password='very secret'
# The access point name you are connecting to
AccessPointName='internet'
# If your device has a PIN code, set it here. Defaults to 'None'
#Pin=None
# Mode can be one of 3Gpref, 3Gonly, GPRSpref, GPRSonly, None
# These only work for Huawei USB modems; all other devices should use None
Mode=3Gonly
# ^ tried all other options too
```

`netctl start mobile_ppp` "connects" silently with no errors on output and shown on `journalctl -xe`, but there's no actual connection.

And it also shows `*` sign prepended on its name when issuing `netctl list` (as if really connected/operating).

Currently I am connected with `netctl` but with `wls1` (Wi-Fi profile set up with `wifi-menu`).

Moreover the USB modem is not shown in the `nm-applet` of NetworkManager, what I installed separately.

Also, the modem's LED turns blue as if connected or operating, but with no results.

I did a lot of research on the web, came across and read wikis and other users asking about similar issues, and tried the solutions, installed many many packages in Arch Linux, but *unfortunately* **nothing worked** for me to simply connect with the modem which used to automatically connect on **Fedora 25** (without GNOME even).

Comment: `lsusb`  with modem. Is usb-modeswitch  usb-modeswitch-data on your system? `nmcli d` and `nmcli c`

Comment: lsusb shows the modems name and manufacturer, and the three ttyUSB's are shown as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could finally solve it (I'm posting it using the USB connection :P).

Some points to note:

- `wvdial` (as configured in `/etc/wvdial.conf`) could not connect anyhow (couldn't dial with `ATDT` and `ATD` commands).
- `netctl` created profile, 'connected' (`netctl start`) without (outputting) errors but there were no real connection.
- So, I installed NetworkManager, started and enabled it as service alongisde ModemManager (with `systemctl start`).
- I installed `tint2` (as there's no panel (system tray) in my system) specifically to run GNOME's `nm-applet` on it, and configured the broadband network, and Network Manager showed it as an enabled device and I could connect through the profile I created on `nm-applet` (GUI, again).

That's it. Thanks, [gnome](/questions/tagged/gnome) for [nm-applet](/questions/tagged/nm-applet) :)

---

NetworkManager won't (probably) connect without ModemManager service.

No matter how hard I'll try I couldn't connect through the default, native `netctl` that comes with [arch-linux](/questions/tagged/arch-linux).

I still would like to connect with the native application, if anyone knows how, or can help with it (reading my previous post, or by providing a 'better' profile file for the USB modem (model) noted above), I'd really appreciate that, and switch back to `netctl`.

But now that the native `netctl` couldn't/doesn't do the job, I'll have them both installed (what I don't actually like doing for minimalism) as network managers until I could connect properly through the former one.